# Скажите пожалуйста как обновить проект через Maven до релизной версии?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Скажите пожалуйста как обновить проект через Maven до релизной версии? В настоящий момент стоит приставка SNAPSHOT. Какие шаги для этого нужно предпринять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы уверены в том, что ваш проект достиг релиза, создайте новый бранч в вашей VCS, и в этом новом бранче уберите приставку SNAPSHOT.